# How to Restrict a column of my pojo to be part of Ignite tables

Tags: cassandra, ignite, cassandra-3.0

I have a pojo that I am using to create ignite caches. now I want to add one more column(XXX) to that pojo and don't want that column(XXX) to be part of ignite cache creation.

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to prepare Cassandra CQL statement: select "customer_ref", "tenant_id", "event_discount_id", "period_num", "domain_id", "event_source", "prod_group_id", "event_seq", "product_seq", "online_version_num", "total_authorised_mny", "version_num", "bonus_count", "customer_category", "***recovery_status***", "total_discounted_usage", "external_balance_liid", "total_online_discounted_mny", "anti_event_disc_mny", "total_partials_mny", "counter_usage", "total_partials_usage", "online_event_count", "event_count", "last_rated_dtm", "account_num", "dyn_alloc_charge_data", "anti_event_disc_usage", "total_usage", "anti_event_count", "last_online_event_dtm", "fast_cache_seq", "total_discounted_mny", "latest_event_dtm", "total_online_discounted_usage", "carried_over_boo", "total_authorised_usage", "total_otc_mny", "online_batch_info", "counter_resets", "total_bonus_award" from "smart"."custprodinvoicediscusage" where "customer_ref"=? and "tenant_id"=? and "event_discount_id"=? and "period_num"=? and "domain_id"=? and "event_source"=? and "prod_group_id"=? and "event_seq"=? and "product_seq"=?;
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.prepareStatement(CassandraSessionImpl.java:603)
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.execute(CassandraSessionImpl.java:201)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name recovery_status
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.prepare(AbstractSession.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.cassandra.session.CassandraSessionImpl.prepareStatement(CassandraSessionImpl.java:585)
        ... 13 more

Answer (score 1):

ignite takes getter and setter method to read and write.

Changed this method signature in that POJO instead of getXXX() and setXXX()

public void **putRecovery_status**(Integer RECOVERY_STATUS) { this.RECOVERY_STATUS = RECOVERY_STATUS; }

public Integer **fetchRecovery_status**() { return RECOVERY_STATUS; }

Comment: Yes you are right. Unfortunately, currently Cassandra Store will ignore transient flag. Your solution should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make a field end up in Ignite cache, you can probably mark it `transient`.

Comment: @Transient
    private int RECOVERY_STATUS;
Added like this, still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I'll look into it